# CMFCEditBrowseCtrl using CWinApp appears as a classic textbox

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I've been trying to add a folder browser using the ressource view, to an existing MFC interface (**MFC EditBrowse Control**). The project uses **MFC in a shared DLL**.

But instead of having a folder browser, I end up with a text box, and when the dialog is initiated an error message pop up "*Un argument non valide a été détecté*" (An invalid argument was encountered).

I already have a similar project with folder browser that works, but I created it from scratch so I was able to use **MFC in a static Library**, which seems to be the main difference.

I've found information about including `"afxribbon.rc"` in the .rc file, it was indeed a difference between the 2 projects, but including it didn't fixed the issue.

```
BEGIN
    "#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEU)\r\n"
    "#ifdef _WIN32\r\n"
    "LANGUAGE 7, 1\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(1252)\r\n"
    "#endif //_WIN32\r\n"
    "#include ""res\\FAROSDKDemoApp.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""l.deu\\afxres.rc""          // Standard components\r\n"
// part that I added
    "#if !defined(_AFXDLL)\r\n"
    "#include ""afxribbon.rc""   // MFC ribbon and control bar resources\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
// end of the part that I added
    "#endif\r\n"
    "\0"
END
```

The other part in the .rc file :

```
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//
#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE 7, 1
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32
#include "res\FAROSDKDemoApp.rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources
#include "l.deu\afxres.rc"          // Standard components
// part that I added
#if !defined(_AFXDLL)
#include "afxribbon.rc"   // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
#endif
// end of the part that I added
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

I've also read about using `CWinAppEx` instead of `CWinApp` for my main class, but my second project uses CWinApp (without any issue). Moreover, when I try to switch to CWinAppEx, it says : *incomplete type is not allowed* and many other variables in the `InitInstance()` function definition are therefore undefined.

Here are the folder browser related declaration :

**Header file :**

```
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl m_FolderPathCtrl;
```

**Cpp file :**

```
void CFAROSDKDemoAppDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
[...]
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FOLDERBROWSER, m_FolderPathCtrl);
[...]
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFAROSDKDemoAppDlg, CDialog)
[...]
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_FOLDERBROWSER, &CFAROSDKDemoAppDlg::OnEnChangeFolderbrowser)
[...]
BOOL CFAROSDKDemoAppDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
[...]
        if (::IsWindow(m_FolderPathCtrl.m_hWnd))
            m_FolderPathCtrl.SetWindowText(m_FolderPath); // display the default path

    // m_FolderPathCtrl.EnableFolderBrowseButton();
[...]

void CFAROSDKDemoAppDlg::OnEnChangeFolderbrowser()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialog::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here

    UpdateData(true);

    try {
        m_FolderPathCtrl.GetWindowText(m_FolderPath);
    }
    catch (...) {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Program failed to access this folder.", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
    }

    UpdateData(false);
}
```

Do you have any suggestion to make the folder browser work ?

Comment: Do you call `EnableFolderBrowseButton()` somewhere?

Comment: I used to call it right after `m_FolderPathCtrl.SetWindowText(m_FolderPath); ` but it didn't make any difference. (`m_FolderPathCtrl.EnableFolderBrowseButton();`). And it was not done in my second project.