# Issue enabling folder browse button on CMFCEditBrowseCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, afx

Here's what the resource manager shows for this particular EditBrowseCtrl. You can see that the "Browse Mode" option is set to "Folder Browse".
[image: resource editor view]

And here's what the actual dialog box looks like when I run the program(no browse button):
[image: no browse button]

I've also tried to enable the folder browse button via the `EnableFolderBrowseButton` method, but the following just gives me a generic "encountered an improper argument" exception.

```
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl* pEdit;
pEdit = (CMFCEditBrowseCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE);
pEdit->EnableFolderBrowseButton();
```

As requested, here's the contents of the .rc file:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog Info
//

IDD_PREFERENCES_PROPPAGE DLGINIT
BEGIN
    IDC_MFCLINK1, 0x37c, 175, 0
0x4d3c, 0x4346, 0x694c, 0x6b6e, 0x555f, 0x6c72, 0x733e, 0x7379, 0x616c, 
0x2e74, 0x6f63, 0x3c6d, 0x4d2f, 0x4346, 0x694c, 0x6b6e, 0x555f, 0x6c72, 
0x3c3e, 0x464d, 0x4c43, 0x6e69, 0x5f6b, 0x7255, 0x506c, 0x6572, 0x6966, 
0x3e78, 0x7468, 0x7074, 0x3a73, 0x2f2f, 0x2f3c, 0x464d, 0x4c43, 0x6e69, 
0x5f6b, 0x7255, 0x506c, 0x6572, 0x6966, 0x3e78, 0x4d3c, 0x4346, 0x694c, 
0x6b6e, 0x545f, 0x6f6f, 0x746c, 0x7069, 0x3c3e, 0x4d2f, 0x4346, 0x694c, 
0x6b6e, 0x545f, 0x6f6f, 0x746c, 0x7069, 0x3c3e, 0x464d, 0x4c43, 0x6e69, 
0x5f6b, 0x7546, 0x6c6c, 0x6554, 0x7478, 0x6f54, 0x6c6f, 0x6974, 0x3e70, 
0x4146, 0x534c, 0x3c45, 0x4d2f, 0x4346, 0x694c, 0x6b6e, 0x465f, 0x6c75, 
0x546c, 0x7865, 0x5474, 0x6f6f, 0x746c, 0x7069, "\076" 
    IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE, 0x37c, 42, 0
0x4d3c, 0x4346, 0x6445, 0x7469, 0x7242, 0x776f, 0x6573, 0x4d5f, 0x646f, 
0x3e65, 0x3c32, 0x4d2f, 0x4346, 0x6445, 0x7469, 0x7242, 0x776f, 0x6573, 
0x4d5f, 0x646f, 0x3e65, 
    0
END
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue does not duplicate using a barebones MFC dialog, so there must be differences elsewhere in the code not shown. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello again @dxiv. I can temporarily make the project public if necessary. That seems like the only way I'm going to be able to solve this problem, as I need the problem fixed in my current codebase, and I have no earthly idea where the issue could be.

Comment: Can you please show the RC snippet of the control from your dialog resource file?

Comment: I saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362484/cmfceditbrowsectrl-using-cwinapp-appears-as-a-classic-textbox. Out of interest are you using `CWinApp` or `CWinAppEx`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've posted the RC snippet. I saw that issue as well, but at the time I thought it didn't apply to me for some reason... I am using CWinApp. Will attempt to change it to CWinAppEx and get back to you.

Comment: Changing the base app class from ```CWinApp``` to ```CWinAppEx``` does not fix the original issue with the resource view option failing to work, but it does give me a different error( ```Exception thrown: read access violation.
pOldData```) when attempting to enable the browse button with the code above.
Seems like it might be having an issue with the edit control not having a value already set?

Comment: Just one observation, the RC data you displayed was not for the actual control on the dialog but was initialization data. The actual control on the dialog itself would look a bit like `CONTROL         "",IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE,"MfcEditBrowse",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80,17,51,330,14` in the file. It is in a different location of the RC. But not to worry. :)

Comment: Ah, thank you for letting me know. IDK why, but I still feel compelled to post it, so here it is:
```CONTROL         "",IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE,"MfcEditBrowse",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80,182,18,80,14```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that my issue was overriding `OnInitDialog` without calling the base class `OnInitDialog` (`CDialogEx::OnInitDialog`).

Comment: Ah, yes. You always need to call your base classes, which is normally added by default when you add your overrides via the IDE. Well done on resolving the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This was definitely an oops on my part. I wrote this particular function override "by-hand", which kind of caused the issue.